# className of element is undefined in loop over <ul>’s childNodes

Tags: javascript

I have this constant declared above my code:

```
const children = todoList.childNodes;
```

Where `todoList` is basically an `<ul>`.

I'm going than to generate the `<li>` item dinamically trough JS, and assign those certain classes in depending of what they are.

Then i have written this piece of code, inside an if/else statement inside a function:

```
for (let child of children) {
  console.log(child.className);
}
```

This works fine and i can see all the classes assigned to this elements.

But then, when i try to access the classes with:

```
 if(cild.className.contains("cross")){
    ......
   }
```

or

```
if(cild.className.includes("cross")){
        ......
  }
```

i have this error : `TypeError: can't access property "contains", child.className is undefined`

What can i do?

Comment: Please post a verifiable example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to use `classList`. Note that since you are using `childNodes`, you will get non-`HTMLElement` nodes. To use `className` or `classList` you need to check if the node is a `HTMLElement`. If you use `children` instead of `childNodes`, all the nodes will be `HTMLElement`s, so no need to check.

```js
for (node of document.body.childNodes) {
  if (!(node instanceof HTMLElement)) // You don't need this check if you replace document.body.childNodes with document.body.children in the above line.
    continue;

  if (node.id === "element") {
    console.log(node.classList.contains("class1")); // true
    console.log(node.classList.contains("class4")); // false

    // Do not use className because it will match any substring of a class
    console.log(node.className.includes("class")); // true
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="element" class="class1 class2 class3"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

- [`childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes) includes all node types, not just element children. Text and comment nodes are examples of common nodes that don’t have `className`. You can use [`children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children) instead.
- `className` is a string. You’re looking for [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).

```js
const {children} = todoList;

for (let child of children) {
    if (child.className.contains("cross")) {
        // ⋮
    }
}
```

Comment: How this answers this `TypeError: can't access property "contains", child.className is undefined`?

Comment: @Ele: “text and comment nodes are examples of common nodes that don’t have `className`”

Comment: I think the OP should post more details about the problem because s/he wrote *This works fine and I can see all the classes assigned to these elements*.  Therefore, your answer it's an assumption of the problem s/he is facing on.

Comment: @Ele: There’s no contradiction with the classes being assigned correctly and the loop failing, but sure, a concrete example would be an improvement.